# Show there are basis vectors such that $Dg(a)(e_{j_k})$ spans $\mathbb{R}^p$

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds

Given $p<n$, $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^p$ a $C^1$ function with $g(a)=0$ and $Dg(a): \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^p$ surjective. And using the identification $\mathbb{R}^p\cong \mathbb{R}^p\times \{0\}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$.

I have to show that there are $j_1<...<j_p$ such that $Dg(a)(e_{j_k})$ for $k=1,...,p$ spans $\mathbb{R}^p$.

**What I have tried:**
Since $Dg(a)$ is surjective, we know that the image of $Dg(a)$ equals and thus also spans $\mathbb{R}^p$.
We also know $Dg(a)$ is linear, so $Dg(a)(e_1 + e_2)=Dg(a)(e_1)+Dg(a)(e_2)$ for example.
So I guess I have to show that if two vectors are linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^n$ they are still linearly independent under the transformation that is $Dg(a)$?

**I also know** that if $A\in \text{Lin}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^p)$ has rank $r$, then there exist $\Phi\in\text{Aut}(\mathbb{R}^p)$ and $\Psi\in\text{Aut}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that
$$
\Phi\circ A\circ \Psi(x) = (x_1, ..., x_r, 0, ..., 0)\in\mathbb{R}^p,
$$
but I don't know if that's useful and how I'd use it. What would be the rank of $Dg(a)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^p$ is linear and surjective, then $Ge_1,...,Ge_n$ must span $\mathbb{R}^p$ and hence must contain a basis.

Comment: But does that mean that only $p$ of those $Ge_i$ span $\mathbb{R}^p$ and why?

Comment: No, it means that you can choose $p$ of them so that they span $\mathbb{R}^p$. There may be some freedom to pick. For example, with $f(x,y) = x+y$ you can choose $e_1 $ of $e_2$.

Comment: How do we know that $p$ linearly independent vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are also linearly independent after being transformed by $Dg(a)$?

Comment: If the vectors $s_1,...s_p \in \mathbb{R}^p$ are linearly independent and $s_k = G b_k$ then $b_1,...,b_p$ must be linearly independent.